# what does id <SampleProtocolDelegate> _delegate mean in objectiveC

Tags: objective-c

I am currently in the process of learning ObjectiveC.
I wanted to know what the following  statement means

```
id <SampleProtocolDelegate> _delegate;
```

I got this from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm)

I know that id is the type but what is `<SampleProtocolDelegate>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is not `id`, the type is `id <SampleProtocolDelegate>`. Which effectively means `_delegate` is a reference to an object which implements the protocol of type `SampleProtocolDelegate`.

If you don't know fully what a delegate is and the delegate pattern then read up about them then come back to the code later.
A delegate is not something specific to Objective-C, a delegate is a common pattern in many languages.

What is specific to Objective-C is that `id <SampleProtocolDelegate>` is Objective-C's syntax for declaring the reference to the object implementing the SampleProtocolDelegate "protocol" i.e. its API.

If my explanation is confusing, just read up about the delegate pattern from a high level point of view first.

Answer (score 0):

`<SampleProtocolDelegate>` means that the object (_delegate) conforms to the SampleProtocolDelegate. 
I.e. it implements the required methods of the protocol.

Comment: In this case, it will be a class that implements `processCompleted`

Answer (score 0):

"SampleProtocolDelegate" is a protocol.

> A protocol is a list of method declarations. If your class adopts the
>   protocol, then you have to implement those methods in your class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1

"_delegate" is object of some class that conforms to "SampleProtocolDelegate" protocol.